# getting null value of button

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a todo app. I create add button which is working perfectly fine. But, the trash button it keeps on returning null value.
I can not find solution on the google i didnt find the solution.
Can Anybody Help me here

```js
var todoList = document.getElementById("todolist");
var addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
var taskName = document.getElementById("task-name");
var trashBtn = document.getElementById("trash");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addFunction);

function addFunction() {
  var task = document.createElement("div");
  task.classList.add("task");
  var tname = document.createElement("li");
  tname.setAttribute("id", "li-task");
  var trash = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  trash.setAttribute("id", "trash");
  trash.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  tname.appendChild(trash);
  task.appendChild(tname);
  todoList.appendChild(task);
}

console.log(trashBtn);
console.log(addBtn);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header>
    <h1>Doer's List</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="add-task">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="task-name">
      <button id="add-btn" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="to-do-list">
    <ul id="todolist"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help Here

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Trash Button by id AFTER you've added it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I instead of creating new variable trashBtn, I used the variable which is define when creating Elemnt.